# Cakephp3 Order by ASC not working

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am trying do retrieve a list of birthdays for the current month but result will look like this:

January 1
January 12
January 2
January 23
January 3

How might I rewrite my query to make it work so they are in order, here i my query:

```
    $month = date("F");
    $clients = $this->Clients;
    $query = $clients->find();

        if($this->Auth->user('role') !== 'admin'){
            $query->where(['user_id =' => $this->Auth->user('id')]);
            $query->where(['dob LIKE' => '%'.$month.'%']);

            $query->order(['dob' => 'ASC']);
        }



    $this->set([
    'clients'=>$this->paginate($query),
    '_serialize'=>['clients'],

    ]);
```

Comment: Somewhat related question: Why don't you store the date in a proper date type column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your dob column is varchar above result is true and expected
you need change datatype to datetime or timestamp
aftar date you can use

```
$query->order(['dob' => 'ASC']);
$query->orderAsc('dob');
```

and you can use date functions instead of LIKE

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to get the current month and order them

Comment: varchar column is not good and you could not sorting currectly